Ferrite bead vs feed through capacitors for LPDDR4

I am designing a TI's AM6442 processor board

I am using SK-AM64x their development board as desgin reference.

There are two version an older and a newer

Old version schemtatic:


New version schematic:



Differences I noticed:


1.)Older design has supplies branched out into multiple rails like VDD_LPDDR4 main supply is divided into VDDQ_LPDDR4_1V1 and VDD2_LPDDR4_1V1. Newer is directly powered through the common VDD_LPDDR4.
2.)Older design uses ferrite beads in series while branching out the above mentioned supplies. The newer design doesn't
3.)Newer design has added some feed through capacitors.

Questions:

1.)Is it OK to power LPDDR4's VDDQ and VDD2 from a common supply?
2.)Why did TI remove ferrites and put feed through capacitors instead?
3.)Why are both terminals of feed through capacitors shorted? How do they work? Shouldn't the be in series like ferrites from old design? Do they work by eating interference nearby of the power-plane and on the power-plane where they are placed?
4.)Where do I learn to use them? Can't find on the internet how to use them.

I can't speak for why TI changed their design, but connecting both ends of a feedthrough capacitor together is a valid approach - it basically acts the same way as a regular decoupling capacitor, but one with extremely low ESL (parasitic inductance) which allows them to be effective at filtering much higher frequencies than a 2 terminal capacitor.

They probably just didn't need them.  If you want to know for sure, I would suggest asking them; TI has a support forum at https://e2e.ti.com/.
Adding ferrite beads complicates the PDN (power distribution network), making things more involved generally.  That's mostly a design issue, but does have knock-on costs for added components (particularly ferrite beads and bulk caps).  Whether they're concerned about costs for an eval board, who knows.  (Was this even an eval board, or a different kind of product?)
Removing filtering has the downside that locally generated ripple is spread further over the board (whatever else is connected to it, and wherever it's routed), and outside noise is coupled in.
Generally, it's feasible to provide enough filtering by local and overall-board bypassing, to keep supply ripple within reasonable bounds, at relevant frequency ranges.  Ballpark, that might be <5% peak voltage ripple, for expected current loads (assume worst-case step change e.g. device starts and stops operation suddenly), at up to PCB-relevant frequencies (typically 100MHz).  PDN impedance, at higher frequencies, is largely limited by pin and bondwire count and length; which is in part why SoCs have onboard bypass capacitors (on the interposer, or die itself).
General purpose digital devices are generally quite tolerant about supply quality, and exceptional filtering is not required.
DDR is a digital IC and interface, and I would be surprised if average amounts of filtering do not also suffice.  Mind that these are high speed interfaces, and signal quality matters; use many ground planes, stitched with vias (and with bypass capacitors to power planes), and impedance-controlled traces.  Via stub backdrilling may be necessary, and so on; but these are layout techniques documented in the devices or interfaces themselves, and not directly germane to the question here.
Which leads into the second main point/question:
The feed-thru capacitors you're referring to, I assume, are Johanson X2Y® capacitors.  (You didn't give a part number or BOM excerpt to confirm this, so I'll just go with this assumption as example.)  With suitable layout, these act like parallel pairs of capacitors, reducing stray inductance for given component count.
Personally, I'm not impressed: they're boutique items, expensive, single sourced*, and most of what they solve is already documented in the appnotes -- or put another way, if you don't follow the layout detail, they're as good as anything else in the same size.  And those same layout techniques save just as  much ESL in any other form factor as well.
*I see possibly a second source from Pulse Electronics, but whether they're direct competitors, licensed, or rebrand/resold, I don't know.  It is suspicious that both companies sell products into the same market segment with the same "X2Y®" label, which makes me suspect they're licensed.
Namely, consider the Johanson EMCT250W104M1GV001E, $0.213/1000s at Digikey right now.  This might replace 2-4 x 0402s, and compare e.g. Samsung CL05A104KA5NNNC at $0.0025/1000s.  But that's not all: not only can we choose a low-inductance arrangement for, say, a pair of 0402s side-by-side, but we can do even better with a wide-format, say 0306: AVX 0306YD104KAT2A shows $0.0533/1000s, which is shorter and wider than a pair of 0402s in parallel are (ESL scales as length and ~inversely with width).
All three options may disappear under your assembly costs; a ballpark prototype cost in the ballpark of $0.10/part isn't unusual, but this varies wildly with quantity, location (domestic vs. outsourced), method (automated PnP vs. varying degrees of manual assistance or placement), and even just subtle quirks of the BoM itself (e.g., having to add or swap out feeders during a run).
It might also be that you're discouraged from using 0402 or finer parts (budget assemblers may charge extra, or not have the capability at all), or that the X2Y just happens to fit better, say in the matrix of vias behind a BGA part, while being a larger (easier assembled) part overall.
In short, if you really need to know the placement cost, consult with your assembler, and discuss cost optimization options.
For production runs under a thousand or so, I doubt it would matter; you can easily spend as much time engineering the alternative layouts as will be saved in the process.
Likewise, if you have specific filtering or timing requirements (a low-jitter FPGA based timing system, say), take the time to optimize the design -- whether it's using X2Y, conventional, wide-format or otherwise.  It may even be that a combination of the above works out best, or that your solution is best found through other means (e.g. consider differential interfaces, over single-ended interfaces whose input thresholds are proportional to supply voltage).

Yes, you are right they are similar to  "Johanson X2Y® capacitors". So if cost is not a concern do you suggest I stick with the ferrites?

I specifically did not suggest a plan of action; if you absolutely must have design confidence, I would suggest hiring an engineer to share your complete design with, and run through calculations on -- I don't have enough information here to make such a decision (nor can I justify spending the time to check it, I'm afraid). Otherwise, studying PDN analysis is the way to go, with whatever combination of methods you find suitable: theory, simulation, measurement, etc. I would expect ferrites and X2Ys are not necessary, but I don't know anything about the exact chips you're using.
